# Yesod errors when compiling

Tags: haskell, yesod

For AForm I have got some compile errors:

**1. For default Int value:**

```
data Person = Person
    { name  :: Text
    , age   :: Maybe Int
    }
    deriving Show

formPerson :: AForm Handler Person
formPerson = Person
    <$> areq textField "Person Name" Nothing
    <*> aopt intField "Person Age" (Just 25)
```

Error  message:

```
No instance for (Num (Maybe Int)) arising from the literal ‘25’
In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘25’
In the third argument of ‘aopt’, namely ‘(Just 25)’
In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
  ‘aopt intField "Person Age" (Just 25)’
```

**2. Error at template:**
getPersonR :: Handler Html

```
getPersonR = do
    let myAge = 25::Int
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "persone")
```

And at template:

```
<span>My age: #{myAge}
```

End error:

```
Not in scope: ‘myAge’
In the splice: $(widgetFile "persone")
```

**3. Error at result:**

```
postPersonR :: Handler Html
postPersonR = do
    ((result, formWidget), formEnctype) <- runFormPost formPerson
    let title = "Success!"::Html
    case result of
        FormSuccess person ->
            defaultLayout $ do
                setTitle title
                $(widgetFile "personresult")
        _ -> 
            defaultLayout $ do
                $(widgetFile "person")
```

and Template:

```
<strong>Your name: #{name person}
```

And error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Person -> a0’
            with actual type ‘blaze-markup-0.6.1.1:Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
                                ()’
The function ‘name’ is applied to one argument,
but its type ‘Html’ has none
In the first argument of ‘toHtml’, namely ‘name person’
In the first argument of ‘asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget’, namely
  ‘toHtml (name person)’
```

How to fix issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 -  Double example - set default value at field and for whole personeForm:**

```
data Person = Person 
    { name  ::  Text
    , age   :: Maybe Int
    }

personeForm :: Maybe Person -> AForm Handler Person
personeForm person = Person
    <$> areq textField "Persone Name" (name <$> person)
    <*> aopt intField "Persone Age" (Just (Just 24))


getAformPersonR :: Handler Html
getAformPersonR = do
    let person = Person "Jack" Nothing
    (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost $ renderDivs $ personeForm $ Just person

    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "aformpersone")
```

**2,3 - Not in scope:**

You used same template for Get ang Post functions. And for that functions you should init same values.